# Using an object property as a variable to multiply a number?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, math

EDIT – I ended up solving it!

Here's the working code snippet: https://jsbin.com/hiqekuwisa/edit?js,console
 (Try doControllerConversion('phase','toRaw'); , etc.)

If I define a variable, in this case, "y" to my object key before any if's or math is done, it works just fine.

Fixed code posted here for reference:

```
function doControllerConversion(selector, orientation) {

    var x; // final auto-input depending on controller type
    var y = userSettings.phaseCurrentLimit; // grab user's desired value (from object)
    var z = userSettings.controllerType; // grab controller type (from object)

    if (z == 'KH606') { //for controller type 1
        if (selector == 'phase') {
            if (orientation == 'toRaw') {
                x = y * 2.85;
                return x;
            } if (orientation == 'fromRaw') {
                x = y / 2.85;
                return x;
            }
        } if (selector == 'battery') {
            if (orientation == 'toRaw') {
                x = y * 5.10;
                return x;
            } if (orientation == 'fromRaw') {
                x = y / 5.10;
                return x;
            }
        } else {
            return MessageOut(1);
        }
    }

    if (z == 'KH609') { //for controller type 2
        if (selector == 'phase') {
            if (orientation == 'toRaw') {
                var x = y * 2.46;
                return x;
            } if (orientation == 'fromRaw') {
                x = y / 2.46;
                return x;
            }
        } if (selector == 'battery') {
            if (orientation == 'toRaw') {
                x = y * 5.10;
                return x;
            } if (orientation == 'fromRaw') {
                x = y / 5.10;
                return x;
            }
        } else {
            return MessageOut(1);
        }
    }

    if (z == 'KH612') { //for controller type 3
        if (selector == 'phase') {
            if (orientation == 'toRaw') {
                x = y * 1.20;
                return x;
            } if (orientation == 'fromRaw')
            return userInput / 1.20;
        }
    } if (selector == 'battery') {
        if (orientation == 'toRaw') {
            x = y * 2.73;
            return x;
        } if (orientation == 'fromRaw') {
            x = y / 2.73;
            return x;
        }
    }
    else {
            return MessageOut(1);
    }

    if (z == 'KH615') { //for controller type 4
        if (selector == 'phase') {
            if (orientation == 'toRaw') {
                x = y * 0.79;
                return x;
            } if (orientation == 'fromRaw') {
                return userInput / 0.79;
            }
        } if (selector == 'battery') {
            if (orientation == 'toRaw') {
                x = y * 2.55;
                return x;
            } if (orientation == 'fromRaw') {
                x = y / 2.55;
                return x;
            }
        }
        else {
            return MessageOut(1);
        }
    }

    if (z == 'KH618') { //for controller type 5
        if (selector == 'phase') {
            if (orientation == 'toRaw') {
                x = y * 0.53;
                return x;
            } else if (orientation == 'fromRaw') {
                x = y / 0.53;
                return x;
            }
        } else if (selector == 'battery') {
            if (orientation == 'toRaw') {
                x = y * 1.70;
                return x;
            } else if (orientation == 'fromRaw') {
                x = y / 1.70;
                return x;
            }
        }
        else {
            return MessageOut(1);
        }
    }
    else { // return general error
    console.log('General error on data conversion!');
    return;
    }

}
```

Thanks for your help everybody!

### Original post below

Within a function, I'm trying to utilize the values of an array property and an object property. They're simple numbers. For some reason, the Array seems to work from inside the function but the object comes back as undefined?

<strike>Here's the code:</strike>

```
function doControllerConversion(selector, orientation) {

    if (rawUserSettings[24] == '1') {
        if (selector == 'phase') {
            if (orientation == 'toRaw') {
                MessageOut(4);
                var x = userSettings.phaseCurrentLimit * 2.85;
                return x;
            } else if (orientation == 'fromRaw') {
                MessageOut(5);
                var x = userSettings.phaseCurrentLimit / 2.85;
                return x;
            }
        } else if (selector == 'battery') {
            if (orientation == 'toRaw') {
                MessageOut(4);
                var x = userSettings.batteryCurrentLimit * 5.10;
                return x;
            } else if (orientation == 'fromRaw') {
                MessageOut(5);
                var x = userSettings.batteryCurrentLimit / 5.10;
                return x;
            }
        } else {
            return MessageOut(1);
        }
    }
```

So I have an array rawUserSettings, which looks like this:

```
 var rawUserSettings = [];

 // unknown, default 2
rawUserSettings[0] = "2"; ///
//////////////////////////

// unknown, default 15
rawUserSettings[1] = "15"; //
//////////////////////////

// phase current limit, amps
// 0-255
rawUserSettings[2] = "255",

// battery current limit, amps
// 0-255
rawUserSettings[3] = "255";

// low voltage cutout, voltage
// 0-255
rawUserSettings[4] = "255";

// tolerance (turn controller back on after low voltage)
// 0-255
rawUserSettings[5] = "255";

// speed limit (0-99%)
// 1-96
rawUserSettings[6] = "96";

// speed mode ("1-4")
// 0-3
rawUserSettings[7] = "3";

// speed 1 setting
// 0-104
rawUserSettings[8] = "104";
```

and so on...

And a more friendly object called userSettings, which looks like this:

```
var userSettings = {
    controllerType: "KH606",
    phaseCurrentLimit: 90,
    batteryCurrentLimit: "70",
    voltageCutoutLimit: "50",
    powerRestoreLimit: "50",
    speedLimit: "45",
    speedLimitMode: "0",
    speedLimit1: "30",
    speedLimit2: "40",
    speedLimit3: "50",
    speedLimit4: "60",
    blockTime: "20",
    autoCruiseTime: "20",
    slipChargeMode: "1",
    ledMode: "1",
```

And so on.

What's going on here? Thanks for your help!

Comment: How do you call `doControllerConversion`? What does `MessageOut` return?

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console? What is `MessageOut`?

Comment: MessageOut(x); simply returns a specificied console message that either gives a confirmation or an error. It’s basically my error handler.

Comment: I get a “userSettings.x undefined.” It can’t pick up anything from this object from inside the function. Any idea why?

Comment: @trincot You can call it like doControllerConversion(‘phase’,’toRaw’); . It’ll detect which model I’m using (that part works) from the raw array, detect if I want to/fromRaw (eg multiply or divide) the object userSettings.X’s value (in this case, userSettings.phaseCurrentLimit, which is a two digit number).

Comment: btw, you could omit the `else` part after `return`, because return ends the function. a simple on going `if` is sufficient.

Comment: @Nina Scholz, will do! Great to know!

Comment: Can you provide a small (! so not the 1000 lines you have on `wire.bike`), runnable snippet, that calls the function and produces the error you mention?

Comment: @trincot, sure! I’ll post it within 30min from now. Thanks so much!

Comment: btw, in `bitFlagsToRaw` (and at some more places!), you do not check the values, but assign the value in the `if` clause, where you included the early exit approach.

Comment: @NinaScholz You’re right, I should comment those lines out as it’s a total work in progress. Right now I’m focusing on specifically the array, the object and the single function noted here. I’ll post a proper sample once I get back at the computer! Thanks so much.

Comment: The offsite code doesn't call `doControllerConversion`. Adding a call after page load didn't produce any errors. Logging the type of `userSettings` said "object".  Make sure to show the call that produces the error to your edited question - and at least check you are not calling it before the declaration of `userSettings`  has been executed (shouldn't be an issue).

Comment: And going out on a limb, check the code you actually used to test doesn't have an edit error and defines `doControllerConversion` twice :-)

Comment: I figured it out, somehow, please refer to my edit question! Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Posting answers inside the question is not helpful for this site. Then you might as well delete the question. Instead, restore the original question, and post the answer as ... an answer. It is acceptable to answer your own questions.

Answer (score 0):

Your function `doControllerConversion` returns `undefined` in many cases. These `if` conditions do not cover all the options. Maybe this is the answer.

Comment: Hey @Sam. rawUserSettings[26] already equals 1. Forgot to include that part of the array. Any other ideas?

Comment: As to your edit — I can’t seem to grab any object’s value, eg “Object.item” from inside a function. However, outside arrays work from inside the function, eg “Object[item]”.

Comment: The if’s work if I remove any reference to the object, if that helps clear things up. :)